# Optimization problem where the objective function returns a function instead of a real number

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

As we all know, a classic optimization problem can be represented in the following way:

> Given: a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from some set $A$ to the real numbers
> Sought: an element $x_0 ∈ A$ such that $f(x_0) \le f(x)$ for all $x \in A$ ("minimization") or such that $f(x_0) \ge f(x)$ for all $x \in A$ ("maximization").

However, I am now dealing with an optimization problem, in which the objective function returns a function instead of a real number. The function has two variables, one is the input variable $x$, the other is an unknown variable $z$ within a known interval. The problem can be described as follows:

> Given: a function $f: A \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(x, z)$ from some set $A$ to a function space $\mathcal{C}(x, z)$ where $z \in [a, b]$
> Sought: a maximum subset $B \subseteq A$, where for each element $x_0 ∈ B$, there exists at least one interval of $z \in [c, d]$ $(a \le c \le d \le b)$, such that $f(x_0, z) \le f(x, z)$ for all $x \in A$ ("minimization") or such that $f(x_0, z) \ge f(x, z)$ for all $x \in A$ ("maximization").

To give a concrete example, say I want to minimize the objective function $f(x, z) = xz^3 - \frac{1}{x} z^2 + z$ where $z \in [-1, 1]$. In the end, I want to get the lowest curve of $f(x, z)$ (scan $z$ from $-1$ to $1$ and connect all lowest parts with different $x$). In my case, I have a finite set of $x$s. The expected result is a subset of optimal $x$s and the corresponding intervals at which $f(x,z)$ is the lowest.

Can anyone suggest how should I approach this kind of problem? I cannot find any literature related to this.

Comment: I think the description needs a little more work. For example, you gave an example of $f:A \times [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$. You should have written $f:A \to C(z)$ and in the example $(f(x))(z)$ instead of $f(x,z)$. Aside from technicalities $B$ just consist of the local minimum points optimized over two parameters according to your definition, because $(f(x_0))(z) \leq (f(x))(z)$ already implies for all $z$ and you require also for all $x$. So, your question is analogue to minimizing a multivariable function unless you mean something else.

Comment: @obareey The difference to an optimization of a multivariable function is that I don't really care about the value of $f(x,z)$, but the position of the curve of $f(x,z)$. The expected optimum is not a real number, but the lowest (or highest) curve, connecting all the $f(x,z)$ segments with different $x$ parameter.

Comment: I get that you want something different than the optimization of a multivariate function. But your description does not reflect this. All I'm saying is that the current description is the same as optimization of a multivariate function. For example, if $f(x,z)$ has a single minimum than $B$ consists of just a point (by your definition).